# Facebook Share Button - see how many referals a "sharer" got

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-sharer

I have a Facebook "share" button on my webpage, and want to implement something that allows users to get a discount on my site if they refer 3 friends. Is there a way I can keep track of how many people clicked on their "share" link? Or if that can't be done, see if their "share" post is still up 12 hours after they click the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API on [links](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=659095587443913%2Flikes) to perform the above operation. There are many SDKs available and you can choose the language that you want to implement in.